# Check URL validity

Tags: iphone, nsurl

Can someone confirm that `-checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:` method of `NSURL` is working as expected. I have tried using it for known URLs and it is always returning `NO`. I am using XCode's iPhone Simulator 4.1.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [NSURL Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios//#/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-SW18)

> Returns whether the resource pointed to by a file URL can be reached.
>  ...
>  **Discussion**
> This method is unimplemented in iOS, so it performs no operation

So it only works for file URLs (which your URL probably isn't) and it only works on Mac OS X anyway.

Comment: In conclusion, for iOS, the answer is NO, right? Any workaround?

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to see if I have an XML at a specific remote location

Comment: You could try using NSURLConnection to access the URL and see if you get valid XML out...

Comment: `-checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:` is intended only for local files at present. You can't use it to check the existence of a remote file on any platform

Comment: @MikeAbdullah Isn't that what I said?

Comment: Seems to be in iOS now (since 5.0): [NSURL Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this method:

```
- (BOOL) validateUrl: (NSString *) url {
   NSString *theURL =
   @"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
   NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", theURL]; 
   return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:url];
   }
```

Comment: This doesn't working correctly. Infant, for some valid URLs it returns NO.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know if the URL is valid, you can

```
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourstring"]];
bool valid = [NSURLConnection canHandleRequest:req];
```