# CFNetwork Error : The connection failed due to a malformed URL

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, cfnetwork

While running iphone app, several times i got the following Error

```
The connection failed due to a malformed URL
```

At `CFNetwork Error Codes Reference`, i got the info that this error triggered by CFNetwork

- When and Why this error is triggered ?
- How to get rid from this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370009/iphone-sdk-check-validity-of-urls-with-nsurl-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSURLConnection has a method canHandleRequest which will return a boolean whether the url is valid or not, e.g.

```
NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.com/stopBoard/%i",busStopCode];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url 
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData 
                                          timeoutInterval:20.0];
// a cache policy of NO must be used otherwise the previous query is used if the phone is not online

BOOL canGo = [NSURLConnection canHandleRequest:request];
if(canGo){
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request 
                                                 delegate:self 
                                         startImmediately:YES];


} else {
    self.errorMessage = @"\n\nurl check failed\n\n";
    return NO;
}
```