# kCFURLErrorBadURL : How to solve?

Tags: php, iphone, url, cfnetwork

I am building a `web service` based on PHP language. `Browser shows the exact data.` But while i am trying get data from my iPhone app then shows the following error

- kCFURLErrorBadURL    = -1000

How to solve the problem from Server End (PHP) ?

Comment: might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383602/cfnetwork-error-the-connection-failed-due-to-a-malformed-url

Comment: @janusfidel, it solves at device end. but i need server end.

Comment: Also check the URL itself, the browser might perform small corrections which are not done with your connectivity class.

Comment: If you are using the same URL it's easy to check it manually (with your eyes i guess or you can try to search for the online validator), it must conform RFC 1738 standard. If the URL is composed, check it's construction. For example `https://www.google.com/?q=search text` is transformed into `https://www.google.com/?q=search%20text` by browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser might bring correction for the URL while the connectivity classes either don't do them or do not the same corrections.

The URL must conform [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), check the URL you are using and make required corrections (preferably on the server side).