# Detect when WKWebview cannot handle a request

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsurl, nsurlrequest, wkwebview

I have the following code

```
NSURL *nsurl = [NSURL urlWithString:@"http://url.that.does.not.exist.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
WKWebViewConfiguration *config = [WKWebViewConfiguration new];
WKWebView *wv = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] configuration:config];
wv.navigationDelegate = self;
```

And the delegate:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView
     decidePolicyForNavigationResponse:(WKNavigationResponse *)navigationResponse
                       decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationResponsePolicy))decisionHandler {
...
}
```

Works fine and I can catch errors when the could not be loaded (404, etc). But how do I catch the error when the `nsurl` was something WKWebView cannot even handle?

For example:

```
NSURL *nsurl = [NSURL urlWithString:@"nacho"];
```

will lead to a blank page with no delegate method being called. How can I handle detect this error? (I have checked at this [iPhone SDK: Check validity of URLs with NSURL not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370009/iphone-sdk-check-validity-of-urls-with-nsurl-not-working) but I wonder if there is anything better than regex?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and see if the url can be requested like this:

```
NSURL *nsurl = [NSURL urlWithString:@"nacho"];

if([NSURLConnection canHandleRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL: nsurl]]){
    NSLog(@"URL can be loaded");
}else{
    NSLog(@"URL cannot be loaded");
}
```

Comment: That works!. It is in NSURLConnection.h there is a big "/*** DEPRECATED: The NSURLConnection class should no longer be used.  NSURLSession is the replacement for NSURLConnection ***/" I wonder if there is a better (non deprecated) approach...

Comment: according to apple https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLConnection the **NSURLConnection** is not totally DEPRECATED. there is still a non DEPRECATED methods