# Finding whether a URL is valid and does it exists?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to find that whether the URL im giving is valid or not, and whether it exists in internet or not..

Is there any way to do that using objective-C?

Comment: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=wwww.googls%40e.c%23om&c=1&m=5&ps=10

Comment: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791067/check-url-validity
2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471201/how-to-validate-an-url-on-the-iphone

Comment: The selected "duplicate" only answers half of the question. It is not a valid duplicate. This should be reopened.

Comment: I second Maddy... the duplicate is not at all an answer of the question: does the URL return an existing endpoint?

Answer (score 2):

You can see if a URL is valid or not by doing the following:

```
NSString *urlString = ... // some URL to check
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
if (url) {
    // valid URL (meaning it is the proper format)
}
```

To see if the URL exists in the Internet, you need to perform a HEAD request and check the result. This is more efficient than loading all of the data for the URL.

```
NSMutableURLRequest request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:inURL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];

NSURLConnection connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    if ([(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode] == 200) {
        // url exists
    }
}
```

Comment: So when you call the connection method, what is the response parameter supposed to be?

Comment: You don't call the `connection:didReceiveResponse:` method. It is a delegate method that it called by the framework when a response is received. See the reference documentation.

Comment: Well. I tested with `http://X  X is a non english character ` and it still pass `[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]`. I think we still need to test with regex like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471201/how-to-validate-an-url-on-the-iphone).