# how to check in iphone app if url is valid then load in WebVIew else show alert

Tags: iphone, ios, url, uitextfield

I have app in which i want that when user enter url in textfield and presses return key it should check if url is valid then load url in web view else show alert enter valid url

In my code it always show Valid URL.

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
  {
   [textField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
   [textField resignFirstResponder];

test=textField.text;

NSLog(@"Test is working and test is %@",test);

[self  urlIsValiad:test];

if ([test isEqualToString:@"Valid"]) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:test]; 
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];         
    [self.webView loadRequest:request]; 
}
 else{

  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please enter Valid URL" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
  return YES;
}
- (BOOL) urlIsValiad: (NSString *) url 
{
NSString *regex = 
@"((?:http|https)://)?(?:www\\.)?[\\w\\d\\-_]+\\.\\w{2,3}(\\.\\w{2})?(/(?<=/)(?:[\\w\\d\\-./_]+)?)?";
/// OR use this 
///NSString *regex = "(http|ftp|https)://[\w-_]+(.[\w-_]+)+([\w-.,@?^=%&:/~+#]* [\w-\@?^=%&/~+#])?";
  NSPredicate *regextest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];

  if ([regextest evaluateWithObject: url] == YES) {
    NSLog(@"URL is valid!");

    test=@"Valid";

  }  else {
    NSLog(@"URL is not valid!");

   test=@"Not Valid";
}

return [regextest evaluateWithObject:url];
  }
```

Comment: There is already some discussions on it in Past [Check Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471201/how-to-validate-an-url-on-the-iphone) or [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833469/regular-expression-for-url)

Comment: @GyanendraSingh i have also got code from that description then what is problem can you help me out please

Answer (score 1):

```
// .h File 
-(BOOL)validateUrl;
.m File
-(BOOL)validateUrl{
    NSString *urlRegEx =  @"((?:http|https)://)?(www\\.)[\\w\\d\\-_]+\\.\\w{2,3}(\\.\\w{2})?(/(?<=/)(?:[\\w\\d\\-./_]+)?)?";
    NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx];
    if ([urlTest evaluateWithObject: self] == YES) {
        NSLog(@"URL is valid!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"URL is not valid!");
    }
    return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:self];
}
// Main View Controller .m File
if (![txtWebsite.text validateUrl])
    {
        [KWebsiteURLTypeValidation showAsAlert:self];
        return;
    }
```

Comment: thanks its work for me, you saved my time to make http|https as optional.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
- (BOOL) validateUrl: (NSString *) url {
   NSString *theURL =
   @"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
   NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", theURL]; 
   return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:url];
   }
```

From [Check URL validity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791067/check-url-validity?lq=1) . Hope this helps.

Comment: what it will reture and how check valid or invalid

Comment: NSString*result=[self validateUrl:testing];

Comment: @QueenSolutions you can implement something like this if([self validateUrl:testURL]){// do this}else{//do that(Show alert) in your case}

Answer (score 0):

i've modified your code so please replace this method with your code and it will work superfine

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

   [textField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   test=textField.text;

   NSLog(@"Test is working and test is %@",test);

   if ([self  urlIsValiad:test]) {
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:test]; 
       NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
       [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
       [self.webView loadRequest:request]; 
   } else {
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please enter Valid URL"  message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alert show];
       [alert release];
   }
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: using this if i enter nice.com then it does not show alert nice.com